# Added objects to an array become undefined

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js, javascript-objects

So, I am writing some code for a command for my Discord bot which adds objects to an array of objects, which is stored in a JSON file. This is the code which achieves that:

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
let blacklist = JSON.parse(rawdata);

var newWord = {"word": args[3], "count": 0}
blacklist.words.push(newWord);

let data = JSON.stringify(blacklist);
fs.writeFileSync('config.json', data);
```

What this does is gets the 4th word in the command (`args[3]`) and puts it in an object (`{"word": args[3], "count": 0}`) and then adds it to the list of objects in the JSON file. This works, however when I then try and get this list of objects, the objects that have been added by the bot are returned as `undefined`.

This is the JSON file:

```
{"words":[{"string":"test","count":0},{"word":"abc","count":0}]}
```

The first object in the list `{"string":"test","count":0}` I added manually when I created the file, however the second object `{"word":"abc","count":0}` was added by the bot.

This is the code I use to get the list of objects:

```
var words = ""
for (i = 0; i < blacklist.words.length; i++) {
    words += "- " + blacklist.words[i].string + "\n";
    console.log(blacklist.words[i].string);
}
message.reply("here are the words in your blacklist:\n" + words);
```

And this is the result:
[image: result of the above code]

I am very new to JavaScript and have been having trouble with its asynchronous nature, so I am sure I am doing something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, you have two different keys defined in your JSON generated file: `string` and `word`. In this case you only see the value of `string` which is `test`. The other object doesn't have the key for `string`.

What you can do is 1. change the keys so they match or 2. Use both keys by using inline if/else.

```
for (i = 0; i < blacklist.words.length; i++) {
    words += "- " + blacklist.words[i].string + "\n";
    console.log(blacklist.words[i].string || blacklist.words[i].word);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < blacklist.words.length; i++) {
>     words += "- " + blacklist.words[i].string + "\n";
>     console.log(blacklist.words[i].string);
> }
> ```

this code want to access blacklist object's words arrays "string" key.
Check your JSON file 2nd element's key it isn't "string"